# printing inside switch , c++ , but outside of cases?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n  ;
    cout << "insert n " <<endl ;
    cin >> n ;

    switch(n){
              cout <<"inside switch " <<endl ;
              case 2 : 
               cout << "this is 2 " <<endl ;
               break ;
              case 5 :
                cout << "this is 5 " <<endl ;
                break ;
              default :
                cout << "this is default - any number" <<endl ;
                break ;

              }

    return 0 ;

    }
```

Does switch structure print the cout before cases?

It does not , i checked it, is this a rule that inside switch only stuff inside cases will be printed?

Comment: Put `cout` outside `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` is essentially just a computed `goto`; the individual cases are essentially just labels.

In your example code, the switch will always jump past the first `cout` statement.

Comment: thanks, now i know that switch will jump past the first cout statement!

Comment: Like Oli mentioned :: works like a jump statement.

But its important if u understand the `break` statement also. If u remove the `break` from `2` and place the `cout` between case `2` and `5` it will print. Coz the flow of the program just passes from `case 2` to `case 5` and everything `in between`.